# Как сделать фиксированный отступ до текста?

Tags: html, css

В верстке часто бывает ситуация, когда, например, нужно сделать отступ от контейнера до текста. Если справа и слева это сделать достаточно просто, то по вертикали попасть в пиксель сложнее. То есть, мы берем линейку и смотрим по макету какое расстояние от границы контейнера до заглавной буквы текста. Но, если задать внутренний отступ в контейнере, он будет дополнен междустрочным интервалом текста.

Понятнее спросить на примере. Хочу чтобы у меня визуально отступ от контейнера до текста был определенного размера сверху и снизу и я не хочу зависеть от размера шрифта.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 20px;
  /* Нужен такой отступ до текста! */
  /* Для наглядности */
  color: white;
  background: black;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* Равен размеру шрифта, но отступ до следующей строки есть сверху и снизу. Можно ли как-то сделать только снизу? */
  line-height: 20px;
}


/* Наглядно смотрим интервал */

.container span {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis atque maiores porro totam ipsum voluptatum cum similique, quam esse id eaque perspiciatis distinctio ex provident natus culpa maxime voluptate, dolorem.</span>
</div>
```

Как этого добиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общего решения для всех шрифтов не существует, потому что величина, на которую `line-height` больше высоты буквы `x`, для каждого шрифта индивидуальна. Но вы можете поиграться и подобрать нужное значение для `margin-top`, которое будет в единицах измерения `ex` — это высота буквы `x` используемого шрифта. Также хочу обратить ваше внимание на то, что `line-height` не надо задавать в пикселях, так вам придется постоянно контролировать его наследование, а это лишний геморрой.

В примере ниже вы можете свободно увеличивать-уменьшать размер, но буква всегда будет на красной границе. Обертка `.container__inner` добавлена исключительно для наглядности.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.container span {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: -.4ex;
}

.container__inner {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="container__inner">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis atque maiores porro totam ipsum voluptatum cum similique, quam esse id eaque perspiciatis distinctio ex provident natus culpa maxime voluptate, dolorem.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте  `padding-bottom` в контейнере. Это отступ снизу. Чтобы отступ был только сверху, используйте `padding-top`. Ну и по аналогии `padding-left` и  `padding-right`. От размера шрифта вы не зависите. Отступ всегда будет столько пикселей, сколько вы укажете. Отступы можно комбинировать.

```css
*{ padding: 0; margin: 0; }

.container{
   padding-bottom: 80px;
   color: white;
   background: black;
   width: 300px;   
   font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis atque maiores porro totam ipsum voluptatum cum similique, quam esse id eaque perspiciatis distinctio ex provident natus culpa maxime voluptate, dolorem.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Я не об этом. Смотрите, вот представьте, что вы верстаете по макету, у  вас есть текст в рамочке, вы берете линейку и смотрите в макете сколько пикселей от рамки до буквы и выставляете это расстояние как padding-top контейнера (например 20px), но тут возникает проблема: от буквы до padding будет тоже отступ, соответственно вам уже не попасть так просто в пиксель.